# How do I nest Terraform stacks beyond top level and module

Tags: terraform

Terraform addresses re-use of components via Modules.  So I might put the definition for an AWS Autoscale Group in a module and then have multiple top level resource files use that ASG.  Fine so far.

My question is: how to use Terraform to group and organize multiple top level resource files?  In other words, what is the next level of organization?

We have a system that has multiple applications...each application would correspond to a TF resource file and those resource files would use the modules.  We have different customers that use different sets of the applications so we need to keep them in their own resource files.

We're asking if there is a TF concept for deploying multiple top level resource files (applications to us).

Answer (score 4):

At some point, you can't or it doesn't make sense to abstract any further. You will always have a top level resource file (i.e `main.tf`) describing modules to use. You can organize these top level resource files via:

#### Use Terraform Workspaces

You can use [workspaces](https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/workspaces.html) - in your case, maybe one per client name. Workspaces each have their own backing Terraform state. Then you can use `terraform.workspace` variable in your Terraform code. Workspaces can also be used to target different environments.

#### Use Separate Statefiles

Have one top level statefile for each of your clients, i.e `clienta.main.tf`, `clientb.main.tf`, etc. You could have them all in the same repository and use a script to run them all, individually, or in whatever pattern you prefer; or you could have one repository per client.

You can also combine workspaces with your separate statefiles to target individual environments, i.e `staging`,`production`, for each client. The [Terraform docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/workspaces.html#when-to-use-multiple-workspaces) go into more detail about workspaces and some of their downsides.